# Find the current enclosed in the loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current

Magnetic field at point $(x,y,z)$ is given by $\overrightarrow B = \dfrac{B_0y}{\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}}\hat i - \dfrac{B_0x}{\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}}\hat j $. Find current enclosed in the loop $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

My work

I used Ampere law 
$$ \oint \overrightarrow  B.dl=\mu_0I_{enclosed}.$$
The question had provided the Amperian loop a circle. I want to what I should deal with Magnetic field in vector form?

Comment: You have written amperes law incorrectly.

Comment: What is wrong in ampere law

Comment: As pointed out by user47033 you have written Ampere's law incorrectly (though it is only a relatively minor mistake), you need to replace $\vec B$ by $B$. In detail: $\oint_C \vec B \bullet \mathrm{d}\vec l=\mu_0 I_{\text{enclosed}}$ and if you consider $C$ to be a circle of radius $r$, then $\vec B$ is parallel to $\mathrm{d} \vec l$ so that $\vec B \bullet \mathrm{d}\vec l = B dl$. You next need to take the magnitude of the magnetic field, $B$, constant on the circle $C$, so that you can take the magnitude of $B$ outside the integral.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be easily done

$\overrightarrow B = \dfrac{B_0y}{\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}}\hat i - \dfrac{B_0x}{\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}}\hat j $.

also $r=\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ = constant

now $\overrightarrow {dl}=dx \hat i+dy\hat j$

now you will get the ampere law

$ \oint \overrightarrow  B.\overrightarrow{dl}=\mu_0I_{enclosed}.$

now put the variables

$x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$

and you will get the answer easily. I think as per the site policy I can help up to this much and no further.

EDIT:

$B.dl= \dfrac{B_0y}{\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}}dx - \dfrac{B_0x}{\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}}dy $.

$dl=-r\sin \theta d\theta \hat i + r\cos\theta d\theta\hat j$

$B.dl=\dfrac{-B_0}{r}\left(r^2\sin^2\theta + r^2\cos^2\theta\right)d\theta $

I think further steps are trivial.

Comment: If you take $\overrightarrow {dl}=dx \hat i+dy\hat j$﻿ and $\overrightarrow B = \dfrac{B_0}{\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}}{(y\overrightarrow i - x\overrightarrow j)}$.Then $\oint\overrightarrow B.\overrightarrow dl$ will become zero

Comment: @user346279 please see the edited answer

Answer (score -1):

Put x = rsin(h) and y = rcos(h) and rewrite the B field vector. You will find that it reduces to Bo, in the tangential direction(tangential to the loop at every point).Thus I through the loop is Bo/(Mu_o) and points into the plane of the paper.

Comment: Do you mean $x = r \sin\theta, y = r \cos\theta$?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't write theta so i wrote h.

Comment: Vector B is inside the integral. Integral of Bdotdl

Comment: Although in this case it wont matter sinve B becomes constant. You should state it correctly

Comment: More my mistake, I read it as sinh() and cosh().